# Functioning called immediately with Transition to + onComplete

Tags: lua, coronasdk

A rainbow rotates onto screen and small squares appear along it. However, this happens immediately rather than onComplete. What am I doing wrong?

```
transition.to( rainbow, { time=10000, rotation=90*rainbowRotationDirection, onComplete=objectsOnRainbow()} )
```

This it in context:

```
local function objectsOnRainbow()
print("objectsOnRainbow")
NumberOfPoints = 5
Angle90Degree = math.pi/2
AngleStep = Angle90Degree/(NumberOfPoints-1)
Angle = 0

 for i = 0, NumberOfPoints-1, 1 do


   local x = ((rainbow.height)/2)*math.cos(Angle)
   local y = ((rainbow.height)/2)*math.sin(Angle)
      local x2 = ((rainbow.height-140)/2)*math.cos(Angle)
   local y2 = ((rainbow.height-140)/2)*math.sin(Angle)
    Angle = Angle + AngleStep


rectangleonRainbow = display.newRect(x, display.contentHeight-y, 5, 5)
rectangleonRainbow2 = display.newRect(x2, display.contentHeight-y2, 5, 5)

end
end

local function rainbowAppear()
local sceneGroup = scene.view

rainbow = display.newImageRect(objectSheet, 38, 590, 590)
rainbow.y = display.contentHeight


rainbow.x = 0
rainbowRotationDirection = 1

audio.play(harpSound)
    transition.to( rainbow, { time=10000, rotation=90*rainbowRotationDirection, onComplete=objectsOnRainbow()} )
     sceneGroup:insert( rainbow )
end
```

Comment: Replace `onComplete=objectsOnRainbow()` with `onComplete=objectsOnRainbow`

Comment: Most common mistake when you come from languages where functions return a type to be called later, like c# ;)